# Move camera to bottom GMSMapView IOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

Currently position of camera in map at center always. Please check screen 1 for that.

I want to fix the camera to bottom with offset, just like screen 2.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
let carBearing = self.getBearingBetweenTwoCoordinates(coordinate1: coordinate1, coordinate2: coordinate2)

self.carMarker.position = coordinate1

let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: coordinate1, zoom: Constants.GoogleMapInfo.KZOOM_LEVEL_20, bearing: carBearing, viewingAngle: 65)

DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
}
```

Thanks

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

Comment: can you add some code that you are using for map and positioning its camera.

Comment: @user832 Sample code added. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by giving  padding to your mapview.

```
let mapInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 150, right: 0.0)
self?.mapView.padding = mapInsets
```